# HtmlUnit: how to search for text

Tags: java, htmlunit

In a java project, I have to use HtmlUnit to retrieve the contents of a WebPage.

How can I search for an element that has the contents `123`. It is part of an html document. The referring element has no id, class or name:

```
....
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>456</td>
  </tr>
....
```

It is not possible to convert the whole document into a text and search afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compose the appropriate `xpath` expression. In your case it can be:

```
//*[text()='123']
```

or more generally

```
//*[contains(text(),'123')]
```

To find elements: `page.getByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'123')]")`